# Grabbing latest FX Rates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

MS-SQL2012 here. I've been tasked with grabbing the latest exchange rates from a database. I know there are multiple ways of doing this such as performing a join or using Window Functions but I seem to have an issue getting both to function properly.

The original task is signified below.

Write SQL procedure that returns the most recent available exchange rates given the following mandatory parameters:

- Source currency [SRCCURRENCY]
- Destination currency[CURRENCY1]
- Date [REFERENCEDATE]
- Rate [RATE1]

from the DCURRENCY database.

Your procedure should not include any rates that have been deleted from the system and if a rate does not exist on the date passed into the parameter of the procedure, the most recent available rate before that date should be returned.

I tried writing a join and windows procedure and just ended up with a fudged error. The following are displayed below.

For my understanding, it would be great if someone could tell me which way they would perform it, and why too.

```
SELECT 
   CURRENCY1
   ,SRCCURRENCY
  ,REFERENCEDATE
 , RATE1

SELECT RANK()
 OVER (PARTITION BY SRCCURRENCY ORDER BY CURRENCY1 DESC) AS N

 FROM [DCURRENCY]
```

and via a join;

```
SELECT  [CURRENCY1]
  ,[SRCCURRENCY]
  ,[REFERENCEDATE]
  ,[RATE1]
  FROM [DCURRENCY]
  INNER JOIN (SELECT [CURRENCY1], MAX(REFERENCEDATE) AS [REFERENCEDATE]
  FROM SRCCURRENCY
  ORDER BY REFERENCEDATE DESC
```

I've performed this on other db's before by grabbing the top results but a lack of schema here is making the task a lot more difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are not syntactically correct.  However, the normal way of thinking about this goes:  You are looking for the currency pair with the latest date.

A typical way of solving this uses `row_number()` and looks like:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by srccurrency, destcurrency order by referencedate desc) as seqnum
      from dcurrency d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

There are other methods, but this looks like what you were attempting with the first query.  However, you seem confused by roles of the currency pair in the query and the date.